# Couldn't understand the logic behind code for mulitdeed payout contract

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity-0.5.x

While searching on the web I came across [this page](https://gist.github.com/tomgtbst/3653c62fdfea6a079aa945588ea145f5) the user has created multiple examples of solidity smart contract

On multiple payout deed smart contract I can't understand this line
`duePayouts = duePayouts + paidPayouts > PAYOUTS ? PAYOUTS - paidPayouts : duePayouts;`

[This is the link to example](https://gist.github.com/tomgtbst/3653c62fdfea6a079aa945588ea145f5#file-day9-deed-multi-payout-sol)

If you can please explain how that line works and what are those operators ':' and '?'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That part of code is called "conditional operator" and is mostly used in C++. It is same as this code:

```
if( duePayouts + paidPayouts > PAYOUTS ){
    duePayouts = PAYOUTS - paidPayouts;
}else{
    duePayouts = duePayouts;
}
```

The "?" is like  "if" and ":" is like "else".

**It's Format is like this:**
conditional Expression ? expression1 : expression2;

if the conditional Expression is true, expression1 executes, otherwise if the conditional Expression is false, expression 2 executes.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator:

```
<conditional> ? <if-true> : <if-false>
```

The code in the example can be interpreted as:

```
if (duePayouts + paidPayouts > PAYOUTS) {
  duePayouts = PAYOUTS - paidPayouts;
} else {
    // NOTE: In that case we can just skip section 'else'
    duePayouts = duePayouts;
}
```